# In Python, how do I efficiently check if a string has been found in a file yet?

Tags: python, string, performance, replace

in a Python function I'm writing I'm going through a text file, line by line, to replace each occurence of a certain string by a (numerical) value. Once I'm at the end of the file I would like to know if this string appeared in the file at all.

The function string.replace() does not tell you if anything has been replaced or not so I find myself having to go over each line twice, to look for the string and again to replace the string.

So far, I've come up with 2 ways to do this.

1. For each line:

   - use `line.find(...)` to look for the string, if it hasn't been found before
   - if the string is found, mark it as found
   - `newLine = line.replace(...)`
   - (do sth. with `newLine` ...)
2. For each line:

   - do `newLine = line.replace(...)` first
   - if `newLine != line` mark the string as found
   - (do sth. with `newLine` ...)

Here's my question:
Is there a better, i.e., more efficient or more pythonic way to do this?
If not, which of the above ways is faster?

Comment: Have you tried timing your code using timeit?

Comment: If you are not interested in how many replacements you did, you can stop comparing newLine and line after the first difference

Comment: @Germano Yup, I do something like `hasBeenFound = hasBeenFound or (stringToFind in line)`. (`or` is short-circuit, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something roughly like

```
found = False
newlines = []

for line in f:
    if oldstring in line:
        found = True
        newlines.append(line.replace(oldstring, newstring))
    else:
        newlines.append(line)
```

Because that's the most easily understandable to me, I think.

There may be faster ways, but the best way depends on how often the string will occur in lines. Almost every line or almost no lines, that makes a big difference.

Comment: The string(s) I'm looking for hardly ever occur(s) in the file (but should do so at least once, otherwise I raise an exception). Any pointers on how to optimize the code for that case?

Comment: I've accepted this one as answer because it's the neatest way for what I want to do.

Comment: On almost all lines, this only checks for presence of oldstring (you need to do that always anyway) and doesn't replace. I think it's close to optimal for your case.

Answer (score 0):

This example will work with multiple replacements:

```
replacements = {'string': [1,0], 'string2': [2,0]}

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for key, value in replacements.iteritems():
            if key in line:
                new_line = line.replace(key, value[0])
                replacements[key][1] += 1

# At the end

for key, value in replacements.iteritems():
    print('Replaced {} with {} {} times'.format(key, *value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we anyway have to go through the string twice, I'd make it as follows:

```
import re
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # check encoding
    s = f.read()
oldstr, newstr = 'XXX', 'YYY'
count = len(list(re.finditer(oldstr, s)))
s_new = s.replace(oldstr, newstr)
print(oldstr, 'has been found and replaced by', newstr, count, 'times')
```